# PHP MySQL foreach insert only first array without looping

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
   require 'db-config.php';

   $results = simplexml_load_file('data.xml'); 

   foreach ($results->ROW as $resultinfo) {

    $id=$resultinfo->DATE;
    $name=$resultinfo->NAME;
    $address=$resultinfo->ADDRESS; 

    // insert not works in loop, only first row inserted    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyDB
    (id, name, address) 
    VALUES 
    ('$id', '$name', '$address')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    id = '$id'";    

    // echo works in loop
    echo ‘<div>’.$name.’</div>’;    
    echo ‘<div>’.$address.’</div>’; 

   }

    // Close Connection
   $conn->close();
   ?>
```

Inside foreach, echo is working and listing all data as expected, sql insert is not working as it only insert into the first row, thx for helping again!

Comment: `'$id'->ID'` - This will result in an SQL syntax error.

Comment: We're almost in 2018; I recommend you learn how to use PDO as mysql_query is deprecated. Also, for your own sake, you would be wise to adhere to PSR standards by using { and } in your loops.

Comment: To answer your question on the syntax; if you plan on using PHP as a work-related tool, ask your employer for a copy of JetBrains' PhpStorm.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i added the single quote, but still receiving error

Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: So if you read the error message you receive, what would you guess the problem is?

Comment: sorry for newbie question again, I corrected all mistakes i made, but it only insert the first array

Answer (score 0):

watch out your single quote:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO MyDB
    (id, name, address) 
 VALUES 
    ('$id->ID', '$name', '$address')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    id = '$id'"; 

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO MyDB
    (id, home_score, away_score) 
 VALUES 
    ('$id->FIXTURE_ID', '$name', '$address')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    id = '$id'");
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, i added the single quote, but still receiving error

Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: your connection string requires a user name and probably a password too. check your mysql credential first